# How the author obtains $A \cap \{\tau_2 \leqslant t\}=A \cap\left\{\tau_1 \leqslant t\right\} \cap\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, stopping-times

I'm reading about stopping times in [this](https://ece.iisc.ac.in/%7Eparimal/spqt/lecture-05.pdf) note, i.e.,

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and $\mathcal{F}_{\bullet}=\left(\mathcal{F}_t \subseteq \mathcal{F}: t \in T\right)$ be a filtration on this probability space for an ordered index set $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ considered as time.

**Lemma 1.11.** Let $\tau, \tau_1, \tau_2$ be stopping times adapted to a filtration $\mathcal{F}_{\bullet}$. If $\tau_1 \leqslant \tau_2$ **almost surely**, then $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_1} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\tau_2}$.

**Proof.** Recall, that for any $t \geqslant 0$, we have $\{\tau \leqslant t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$. From the hypothesis $\tau_1 \leqslant \tau_2$ **a.s.**, we get $\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\} \subseteq\left\{\tau_1 \leqslant t\right\}$ **a.s.**, where both events belong to $\mathcal{F}_t$ since they are stopping times. The result follows since for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau_1}$ and $t \in T$, we can write $A \cap\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\}=A \cap\left\{\tau_1 \leqslant t\right\} \cap\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$.

---

**My understanding** The inclusion $\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\} \subseteq\left\{\tau_1 \leqslant t\right\}$ holds almost surely, i.e., it may not hold on a $P$-null set.

> Could you explain how the author obtains the surely inclusion $A \cap\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\}=A \cap\left\{\tau_1 \leqslant t\right\} \cap\left\{\tau_2 \leqslant t\right\}$?

Comment: I guess, usually people assume that the filtration satisfy usual conditions. In particular, all sigma algebras are assumed to be complete. So that one doesn’t have to worry about negligible sets.

Comment: @Raghav I agree. The statement is false in generality. But there are two situations that are usually considered in which the statement is true. 1) We consider countably generated $\sigma$-algebras. In this case, we may simply assume that we do not have sets of null measure. 2) We consider the continuous case and one assumes the "usual conditions". This includes that the filtration is complete, i.e. contains all null sets.

Comment: @Raghav I got it. Could you post the "usual conditions" as an answer?

Comment: @Analyst Let's leave it as a comment. I am not sure if it makes much sense as an answer. Glad that I could clarify. If I get time to think and could come up with simple example where the conclusion would fail without completion assumption, I will write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $\tau _1\leqslant \tau _2$ then
$$
\tau _2\leqslant t\implies \tau _1\leqslant t\\[1em]
\therefore\quad \{\tau _2\leqslant t\}=\{\tau _1\leqslant \tau _2\leqslant t\}=\{\tau _1\leqslant t\,\land\, \tau _2\leqslant t\}=\{\tau _1\leqslant t\}\cap \{\tau _2\leqslant t\}
$$

If $\tau _1\leqslant \tau _2$ a.s. then a similar reasoning show that
$$
\{\tau _2\leqslant t\}=\{\tau _1\leqslant t\}\cap \{\tau _2\leqslant t\}\;\text{ a.s.}
$$
That is, the above equality becomes an almost sure equality.